# STM32 I2C issue with max127

Tags: arduino, stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I am trying to read analog data from [Max127](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX127-MAX128B.pdf) using stm32f4 discovery board. I seem to have setup the gpio pins and i2c correctly. But I seem to be getting a constant value from the i2c. It would be grea if I can find out my mistake, and I would appreciate any help.

Here is the code snipped for enabling GPIO pins

```
__GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
GPIO_i2c.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
GPIO_i2c.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_i2c.Pin |= GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11;
GPIO_i2c.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C2;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_i2c);
```

I have used external 4.7k resistors as pull up resistors which is why I configured them as no pull.

The i2c is initialized as :

```
__I2C2_CLK_ENABLE();
I2cHandle.Instance             = I2C2;
I2cHandle.Init.AddressingMode  = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
I2cHandle.Init.ClockSpeed      = 100000;
I2cHandle.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
I2cHandle.Init.DutyCycle       = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
I2cHandle.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
I2cHandle.Init.NoStretchMode   = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
I2cHandle.Init.OwnAddress1     = 0x30F;
// I2cHandle.Init.OwnAddress2     = 0xFE;
if(HAL_I2C_Init(&I2cHandle) != HAL_OK)
{
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();    
}
```

The address of the chip is configured as 0x28, and the channel number is 0x94. The channel address has to be transmitted first and we get two bytes back with MSB first.So I have written the following code.

```
while (1)
{
Buffer1[0]=0;
Buffer1[1]=0;

while(HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&I2cHandle,(uint16_t)0x50,10,100)!= HAL_OK);

HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&I2cHandle,(uint16_t)0x50,(uint8_t*)0x94,1,10000);

HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&I2cHandle,(uint16_t)0x51,(uint8_t *)Buffer1,2,10000);

result=(Buffer1[0]*256+Buffer1[1])/16;

a=(result%10)+48;
b=((result/10)%10)+48;
c=((result/100)%10)+48;
d=((result/1000)%10)+48;

HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle,(uint8_t *)&d,1,5000);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle,(uint8_t *)&c,1,5000);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle,(uint8_t *)&b,1,5000);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle,(uint8_t *)&a,1,5000);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle,(uint8_t *)&"\n",1,5000);
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_15);
result=0;
HAL_Delay(100);
```

}

I keep getting a constant value. I checked the dac with arduino, and it seems to work fine. Here is the arduino code for your reference:

```
#define ch=148;
#define deviceAddress 0x28
void loop()
{
    Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress);
    Wire.write(ch);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    Wire.requestFrom(deviceAddress, 2);
    int result = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        if (Wire.available()) result = result * 256 + ((Wire.read()));
    data = result / 16;
    Serial.println(data);
}
```

Any suggestions and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank You